# Azure Private link scope with Application insight to monitor application hosted under private network

Tags: azure, azure-private-link, azure-private-dns-zone

I have deployed an web app in Azure VM. The requirement is to monitor this application availability from application insight using private IP because there should not be any public IP for that application.
So I have followed Microsoft documentation and found that it can be done using Azure Monitor Private Link Scope.

I have configured everything following the documentation and the linkscope is in the same vnet with my application vnet but my application insight still cannot connect to the web app using private IP.

screenshots of my configuration

AppInsight

[image]

Connected Azure Monitor Private Link Scope

[image]

Private endpoint connection under Azure Monitor Private Link Scope

[image]

DNS Configuration in private endpoint

[image]

FDQNs

[image]

The application insight should be able to check the availability of the web application using private ip.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I'm experiencing similar issues with private AKS clusters.